# Unable to apply style to button control defined in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to the WPF technology. Currently I am willing to apply master page concept in an WPF application.

I have used ResourceDictionary for the same. I am facing an issue while doing this as per below.

I want list of link buttons to be displayed on my Master page.

As there is no direct link button control available in the WPF I have found a style script used to create a link button as per below.

```
<Style x:Key="Link" TargetType="Button">
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" 
                                                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                                                </Trigger>
                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
```

Now I have a button control used in the ResourceDictionary file and I am trying apply this style to the button control. It compiles successfully but runs with an exception message.

Below is my code of ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSRTC.Master">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
                    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="850"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="D:\Assignments\WPF\MSRTC\Developement\MSRTC\MSRTC\MSRTC\Images\Logo.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Image Source="D:\Assignments\WPF\MSRTC\Developement\MSRTC\MSRTC\MSRTC\Images\HeaderImage1.jpg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill"/>

                                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Silver" Height="400">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Text="Welcome" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Button Name="btnHome" Content="Home" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource Link}"></Button>

                                </Grid>

                                <StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                                <!--<StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">-->
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Abstract}"/>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>
                            <!--<StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Abstract}"/>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </StackPanel>-->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong and how to takle with this.

Also one thing to be mention, the link button style script I have written in App.xaml Application.Resource section.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exception? (Or "inner exception"?)

Comment: Hi Joe,   There is no proper message as such. Just a error message box pops up with the below information                                                                                              An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: If you click on the details, is there an "Inner exception"?

Comment: Hi Joe,  The issue has been resolved. I just changed style StaticResource to DynamicResource and it worked.    Thank you for your help Joe. Have a good day.